# phrets not showing search results

Tags: php, rets

I'm working on phrets. When I use GetMetadataTypes() method it shows result, but, when I do search query, it doesnt, I mean no result.

Currently this is on my local server(XAMPP). Does it works on local server?

My code is here

```
$search = $rets->SearchQuery("Property","RES","(ListDate=1990-01-01+)");
// get the first record returned
$listing = $rets->FetchRow($search);
// get list of fields for our loop
$fields = $rets->SearchGetFields($search);
// loop through each field in the response and pull it's value
foreach ($fields as $field) {
        echo "+ {$field} value is {$listing[$field]}\n";
}
```

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some rets servers which is having classes in which there should be some required fields in the query in order to pull the data. 
egs:
Instead of
 (ListDate=1990-01-01+) , 
you may need to pass the required fields like 
 ((ListDate=1990-01-01+)(Status!=ACT,SLD))
 where "Status" is the required field.